# How to do "make drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko"

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

How can I compile usb-storage.ko (only) from kernel source tree ?

Running kernel version: `2.6.35-22-generic` (uname -r)

Source version: `linux-2.6.35`

1. Doing `modprobe usb-storage` gives the below error.

   `FATAL: Error inserting usb_storage (/lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko): Invalid module format`
2. Doing `insmod` gives the below error.

   `insmod: error inserting 'drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko': -1 Invalid module format`
3. `dmesg` gives as below.

   `usb_storage: no symbol version for module_layout`

How can I change the top level Makefile to get it inserted into running version of kernel ?

**Makefile**(top level)

VERSION = 2

PATCHLEVEL = 6

SUBLEVEL = 35

EXTRAVERSION =

NAME = Sheep on Meth

Comment: show us the unchanged makefile so we know how to change it.

Comment: added, makefile header

Comment: also show us the output of `modinfo (path/to/module)/usb-storage.ko`

Answer (score 4):

During kernel development one often encounters these 2 frustrating errors upon **`insmod`** ing locally built **`ko`** modules.

---

**Error1: `<module-name> no symbol version for module_layout`**

***Why?***
This means that the Kernel source is **NOT** built. Once the entire kernel source is built, then a file **`Modules.symvers`** will be generated in the top-level directory of the Linux Kernel source. This will contain the address of the symbol **`module_layout`**. Henceforth, this will be used when any kernel modules are built.

***Fix***
Build the complete Kernel source. Ensure that **`Modules.symvers`** is generated and it contains a line with the symbol **`module_layout`**. Following this, build the kernel module.

---

**Error2: `<module-name> disagrees about version of symbol module_layout`**

***Why?***
The error means that the kernel source being used differs significantly from the one used to build the kernel image used to boot.

***Fix***
Manually modifying the **`ko`** module file to match the value of **`module_layout`** in the **`ko`** file with the value in the kernel image being used to boot.

To do so we first need to determine the valid value of **`module_layout`**. This is essentially present in each of the valid working **`ko`** files present on the system. A quick way to obtain this info is from a valid **`ko`** file that successfully loads. Use **`lsmod`** to get a list of potential "working.ko" files.

```
# modprobe --dump-modversions <working.ko> | grep module_layout
0x0b11e775      module_layout
# modprobe --dump-modversions <your.ko> | grep module_layout
0x2719d41e      module_layout
```

NOTE: IF there is no instance of **`module_layout`** symbol in your **`ko`** file then first follow steps to fix ERROR1 before proceeding below.

Using your favorite hex editor, find and replace the value (**4** bytes) in your ko file with the value from the working ko file.

Before Modification:
`00016c70`**`1e d4 19 27`**`6d 6f 64 75  6c 65 5f 6c 61 79 6f 75  |u...module_layou|`

After Modification:
`00016c70`**`75 e7 11 0b`**`6d 6f 64 75  6c 65 5f 6c 61 79 6f 75  |u...module_layou|`

---

With the above changes, **`insmod`** ing the locally built **`ko`** file should be successfull.